# React does not rerender component (gradient)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to create a way for a user to customize his background for a div with gradients using https://jonkelley88.github.io/react-gradient/

```
                    <Gradient
                        gradients={gradients}
                        element="Box"
                        angle="30deg"
                        className="box"
                    >
                        <Box  w='100%' p={4} color='white'>
                            <Calendar />

         </Box>

 </Gradient>
```

```
    const [background1, setbackground1] = useState('#fff')
    const [background2, setbackground2] = useState('#000')
    const [background3, setbackground3] = useState('#fff')
    const [background4, setbackground4] = useState('#fff')
    const [gradients, setGradients] = useState([
        ['#fff', '#000'],
        ['#fff00', '#fff'],
    ])
```

```
                            <Button bgColor={background == 'green.800' ? "green.700" : "green.800"} size="xs" mx={1} onClick={() => setGradients([['#12ff00', '#12ff00'], ['#12ff00', '#12ff00']])} />
```

But when I click the button it does  not change the gradient, also I have a console.log(gradients) and it detects when something is changed   but the component stays the same

Comment: Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/JonKelley88/react-gradient/blob/master/src/components/Gradient.js#L13) make me thing that this library doesn't support it

Comment: I was thinking ab the same thing, thx